# prompt for input in a root session in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to read input with `read` command within superuser privilege:

```
sudo read p
```

returns error:

```
sudo: read: command not found
```

And in the following:

```
sudo -s <<EOF
read p
EOF
```

`read` is being skipped.

So, How can I use `read` in a root session in a shell script or is there any alternatives? A little insight about why the above doesn't work would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I want the input to be stored in the variable `p` to be used later. Basically I want to do this inside the heredoc, i.e `p` should be usable inside the heredoc, outside the heredoc it's of no concern.

Comment: Just use `read`, without `sudo`.

Comment: @anishsane: The OP is asking how to use it with `sudo`.

Comment: ^^ That doesn't make any sense. (At least I am not able to make any sense out of it.) `read` will modify a variable in current shell. When run as `sudo`, it should spawn a new process/new shell. Even if you modify a variable in that script, it will not be useful anywhere in latter script.

Comment: @anishsane that's why i am trying the heredoc. can you focus on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could help:

```
$ my_tty=`tty`

$ sudo -s <<EOF
read -p "Some prompt: " p < $my_tty
echo "You supplied '\$p'"... #use $p
EOF

#Output
Some prompt: somevalue
You supplied 'somevalue'...
```

However, as I already said, this `$p` value is not visible outside `sudo`.

You could have rather used it like:

```
$ read -p "Some prompt: " p
$ sudo -s <<EOF
echo "You supplied '$p'"... #use $p
EOF
```

Comment: ^^ Try it... ;) Ok it works. But sometimes you could get `not a tty`, depending on how deep bash nesting you are in...

Comment: Isn't `'\$p'` explicitly not what is wanted there? That variable *wants* to get expanded by the parent shell.

Comment: ^^ My bad. Copy pasted from first code snippet. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo -s read p
```

You can't use sudo for shell built-in commands since sudo doesn't create shell

Comment: When you use -s you specify to run sudo in shell. That is why above sudo command prompts for read. Hope this clarifies

Comment: You may need to edit your question with what do you want to achieve, so that others can give better solution

Comment: will `p` be usable "outside" the sudo shell created by `sudo -s` ?

Comment: This is more a question to @mahesh-kharvi . The shell in the command might not export the variable into the shell running your script, any new sudo shell might not have the old `p` present.

Comment: It is of no use, since it is created in another shell. I just wanted to demonstrate how to use shell built-ins with sudo